# Error while reading mongoUri replicatSet config in spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have mongoUri config set in my properties file like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:3YySgdQLEaeFTN2@mongodb-01.uata.lokal:27017,mongodb-02.uata.lokal:27017/dbName
```

And I receive this error:

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=mongodb-02.uata.lokal:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=84.6 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=mongodb-01:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb-01: nodename nor servname provided, or not known}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb-01: nodename nor servname provided, or not known}}, {address=mongoarb-01.uata.lokal:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_ARBITER, roundTripTime=88.8 ms, state=CONNECTED}]

Please help how should I add the mongo replica set configuration

Comment: Your cluster is down. There is No PRIMARY in the currently available replica set members. This would have either resolved itself by now or you have a "database maintenance issue" and not a "programming question" which is what Stack Overflow is for. If your cluster is still not working, then ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: yeah, I checked there was some issue with our rs setop only. btw thanks for the help @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that the primary was configured using the host name instead of `localhost`, which I could see from `mongosh`:

```js
rs.conf()
cfg = rs.conf()
{
  _id: 'rs',
  version: 2,
  term: 3,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: 'MYHOSTNAME:27017',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    }
  ],
  ...
  }
}
```

It might be necessary to reconfigure the replica set from `mongosh`:

```js
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].host = "localhost:27017"
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

Now the RS member points to `localhost`:

```js
rs.conf()
cfg = rs.conf()
{
  _id: 'rs',
  version: 2,
  term: 3,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: 'localhost:27017',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    }
  ],
  ...
  }
}
```